# How pass the output of a GitLab API call to an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-api

I create a shell script to get the Project ids within a specific GitLab group using GitLab API. Now I want to pass this project ids to an array. Could you make me any suggestions ?

Shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

GIT_API="https://git.XXXXXXXX/api/v4"
GIT_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
GROUP_ID="1079"

curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/$GROUP_ID/projects"| jq -r ".[] .id"
```

I solved this error. My new code is:

```
PID_ARRAY=($(curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/$GROUP_ID/projects" | jq -r ".[] .id"))
```

Comment: What does "pass to an array" mean? Do you want to create a bash array from the ids? What further processing you want to do with the ids? Maybe an array-less solution involving `xargs` or `parallel` would be a better fit...

Comment: Pass mean Storing the output of this command.After that I need to use this array to a another command (Curl).

Comment: Scenario is this: Find the all projects ids within a specific group in GitLab and archive them. First I am gonna do find the project ids and store them in a array using above command.Then archive them one by one using loop and array @liborm

Comment: _pass these ids into an array_  does not mean anything. Do you mean '_create an array where each array element holds one word from the standard output of the command_? If yes, then please write this in this way in your question. If not, then clarify in your question what exactly you want.

Comment: This works for me....Problem solved....PID_ARRAY=($(curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/$GROUP_ID/projects" | jq -r ".[] .id"))

Comment: @DhanushkaEkanayake you can add it as an answer and even accept it - to make it easier to find for others;)